# Как избежать анти-паттерн Busy Waiting

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

У меня тут небольшой класс, который слушает InputStream субпроцесса и отправляет цельное сообщение в callback.

```
private static class StreamListener extends Thread {
    private final Process process;
    private final InputStream stream;
    private final Callback<String, Void> callback;

    private StreamListener(Process process, InputStream stream, Callback<String, Void> listener) {
        this.process = process;
        this.stream = stream;
        this.callback = listener;
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        BufferedReader scanner = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            while (process.isAlive() || scanner.ready() || !buffer.toString().isEmpty()) {
                if (scanner.ready()) {
                    // Если уже есть какой-то ввод, сначала переносим строку
                    if (!buffer.toString().isEmpty())
                        buffer.append('\n');
                    // Добавляем в буффер ввод
                    buffer.append(scanner.readLine());
                } else if (!buffer.toString().isEmpty()) {
                    // Если в этот раз нету данных, но в прошлый раз - был,
                    // значит надо отправить содержимое буффера
                    callback.call(buffer.toString());
                    // и очистить буффер
                    buffer = new StringBuilder();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Недавно я прочитал про [Busy Waiting](https://josephmate.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/how-to-avoid-busy-waiting/). Насколько я понимаю, у меня в методе `run()` проявляется именно он. Как мне его избежать?
Ранее я использовал `Scanner` (вместо `BufferedReader`) с его методом `hasNext()`, который, *вроде как*, безопасно блокирует `Thread`, но мне нужно, что бы многострочное сообщение отправлялось на `callback` цельно, а не построчно.

Или же это все мой маразм и никакого Busy Waiting'а тут нет, либо он пренебрежителен?

Answer (score 1):

С одной стороны, здесь есть цикл с неблокирующими проверками в качестве условия (признак Busy Waiting). С другой стороны, `readLine` внутри цикла - это блокирующее чтение. Даже если результат `ready` будет истинным, то это не гарантирует, что хватит данных для прочтения строки.

Т.е. при полном отсутствии данных будет Busy Waiting, вхолостую пожирающий процессор. Но с одним фактором: при наличии хоть каких-то данных будет блокировка до прочтения полной строки.

Ещё один момент - это неопределенность понятия многострочного сообщения. При такой реализации всё зависит от того, успеет ли `ready` вернуть истину для новых данных или нет.

В принципе, всё зависит от задачи, насколько она требовательна к предсказуемости результата, отсутствию задержек и т.п. Например, при блокировке на чтении уже не проверить живость процесса, остается лишь надеяться, что будет брошено исключении при попытке читать из привязанного к нему `InputStream`. Вторая проблема, которая усложняет написание *"хорошей"* реализации в том, что в общем случае блокирующее чтение из `Reader` не имеет указания тайм-аута. Это бы ощутимо упростило бы код.

А в нетребовательном случае можно обойтись комбинацией блокирующего чтения и `sleep`. Повторюсь, всё зависит от требований.